# Youtube captures user after linking to video from app in iOS (with Sencha)

Tags: video, cordova, youtube, extjs

I want to play a Youtube video in/from my Sencha/Phonegap built app in Android and iOS. But it fails on both Android and iOS. I'm using an `Ext.XTemplate` to dynamically load the youtube video code in the following code sample:

```
'<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" 
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{youtube_url}" 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
```

This fails for me: On Android, my video thumbnail displays with a play button, but when I click it it will not play. On iOS my entire card stays blank. I tried several options mentioned here on stackoverflow.

Trying to work around this, I'm linking directly to youtube via a dynamic thumbnail in the same `Ext.XTemplate`:

```
'<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={youtube_url}">',
'<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/{youtube_url}/0.jpg" class="youtube_thumb"/>',
'</a>',
```

The video now loads fine. Android lets me choose to use the browser or the native app. After playing, the back-button lets me return to my app.

However, new issue: In iOS, the video plays, but there is no way to return to my app. I do not have a back button, and from the multitask bar I see that I'm still in my app. Returning to the iOS home screen and starting my app again I still return to the video. I need to actively close the app from the multitask bar and then start it again all over.

How can I fix this? Either playing the video in my app (and it automatically closes after playing) or linking to the video and really leaving the app so I can return to it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly what you want but I recently did a VideoPlayer plugin for Android that supports YouTube videos.

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/11/video-player-plugin-for-phonegap.html

Comment: Thanks! I've seen and used it indeed, works nicely on Android, but so does linking to Youtube directly for my purpose. If you know of any iOS solution for this that would be great. Although I'm trying to keep the code base in sync over platforms. Hence the Sencha choice.